# Multiple Waypoints with react-google-maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

When using the `react-google-maps` library. I've found the [`DirectionsRenderer`](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#directionsrenderer), but I only see an origin and a destination included as the options.

Is it possible to include multiple waypoints?

[Google Maps API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints)

Comment: Just FYI to anyone visiting...this project was a mix of React and Laravel Blade views so since the response from the maintainer was essentially "figure it out". Which is totally fine (he provided a tool that fit 80% of what I needed). The budget for this particular project didn't cover figuring it out so I just exited React and switched back to a basic view that followed the examples provided by google.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can include multiple waypoints. As you see in the [DirectionsRenderer sample](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#directionsrenderer), it uses `const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();` . You can follow the sample on the [DirectionsService doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#:%7E:text=Below%20is%20a%20sample%20DirectionsRequest%3A) on how to include the Waypoints in your request.

Here's a sample code snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  DirectionsRenderer,
} from 'react-google-maps';
class Map extends Component {
  state = {
    directions: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    const origin = { lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 };
    const destination = { lat: 41.756795, lng: -78.954298 };
    const waypt = [
      {
        location: { lat: 40.278022, lng: -76.899615 },
        stopover: true,
      },
      {
        location: { lat: 40.750216, lng: -78.922049 },
        stopover: true,
      },
    ];

    directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        waypoints: waypt,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      },
      (result, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          this.setState({
            directions: result,
          });
        } else {
          console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    const GoogleMapExample = withGoogleMap((props) => (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.756795, lng: -73.954298 }}
        defaultZoom={13}
      >
        {this.state.directions && (
          <DirectionsRenderer directions={this.state.directions} />
        )}
      </GoogleMap>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMapExample
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `500px`, width: '500px' }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```